# Fetch email from AspNetUsers table using default User.Identity.getUserName() to another view(from another table) and disable the field

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

I have an ASP.NET MVC 5 application where a user (employer) registers entering email and password from the default Account/Register action and then redirects (if successful) to another action (Employer/Create).

I have an employer model (`Employer.cs`) in the project with email as one of the properties. When the view (Employer/Create) is displayed, I want the email field to be disabled but still show the email from the `AspNetUsers` table (the one used to register) so that the user cannot enter a mail different from the one in `AspNetUsers` table.

Here is my code:

Account/Register

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Register", "Account", FormMethod.Post, new { @class = "form-group", role = "form" }))
            {
                <div class="col-md-4" id="log">
                    <h3>Register</h3>
                    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
                    <h4>Create a new account.</h4>
                    @Html.ValidationSummary("", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                    <div class="form-group">
                        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Email, new { placeholder = "Email", @class = "form-control, textbox" })
            }
```

and Employer/Create

```
    @using (Html.BeginForm("Create", "Employer", null, FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
    {
        @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

        <div class="col-md-6" id="log">
            <h3>Welcome</h3>
            <h4>Kindly create a profile to connect with talented techies</h4>
            <hr />
            @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            <div class="form-group">
                @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Email, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control,text-box", placeholder = "Email address", value=TempData["Email"], @readonly ="readonly" })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Email, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>
   }
```

and the Employer Controller

```
public ActionResult Create([Bind(Include = "ID,CompanyName,Email,CompanyWebsite,Address,Field")] Employer employer)
        {
            employer.Email = User.Identity.GetUserName();
            TempData["Email"] = employer.Email;
            try
            {
                if (ModelState.IsValid)
                {
                    db.Employers.Add(employer);
                    db.SaveChanges();
                    return RedirectToAction("Details", "Employer", new { Message = ManageController.ManageMessageId.CreateProfileSuccess, id = Model.ID  });
                }
            }
           ...
        }
```

I tried using `TempData`, but to no avail. How do I get to work?

**The register action:**

```
         public async Task<ActionResult> Register(RegisterViewModel model)
                    {
                        using (var context = new ApplicationDbContext())
                            if (ModelState.IsValid)
                        {
                            var user = new ApplicationUser { UserName = model.Email, Email = model.Email };
                            var result = await UserManager.CreateAsync(user, model.Password);
                            var roleStore = new RoleStore<IdentityRole>(context);
                            var roleManager = new RoleManager<IdentityRole>(roleStore);
                            var userStore = new UserStore<ApplicationUser>(context);
                            var userManager = new UserManager<ApplicationUser>(userStore); 
        userManager.AddToRole(user.Id, "Employer");
        if (result.Succeeded)
                            {
                                await SignInManager.SignInAsync(user, isPersistent:false, rememberBrowser:false);
                               ...
                             return RedirectToAction("Create", "Employer");
                            }
                            AddErrors(result);
                        }
                       // If we got this far, something failed, redisplay form
                      return View(model);
                   }
```

**The HttpGet request for the create action**

```
public ActionResult Create()
        {
            return View();
        }
```

Comment: With which issues you encountered and where?

Comment: Your `Create` action redirects to the `Details` action once you save, AND it already sets the email address to be readonly.  I think we're going to need your `Register` action, the `Details` view and the models that you're using.

Comment: @BrendanGreen the Register action is now included

Comment: @kat1330 the email field is disabled(thanks to readonly attribute), but the email from the register action is not passed to it i.e it is empty

Comment: That;s because you don't pass a model to the `Create` action.  What model are you using in the Create `HttpGet` (not the `HttpPost`) action?

Comment: @BrendanGreen Seems that's where the problem is. I've updated my code with the HttpGet request for the Create action. Please kindly advice on what to include. Thanks

Comment: You don't need to `RedirectToAction(...)` in your `Register` action.  Instead, just return the `View("Create", model)`, and update the `Create` to accept a model of `RegisterViewModel`, making sure you account for cases when it is `null`.

Comment: @BrendanGreen this is the point it's becomes not  so clear. please help guide